# Extracting an integer from a string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a personal ID and an Industry ID that I would like to compare with each other, but the industry number has zeros and an alphabet character in front. and some numbers are longer than others.

ex.

```
Personal Number | Industry Number
123             | J000123              
1234            | L001234
12345           | M012345
```

I know how to solve the problem if it was ONLY zeros. Character throws me  around, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Some example of your tries, some code? Or maybe you want finished solution?

Comment: there is a whole page dedicated to trimming if thats what you want
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you have only one character in the beginning for all lines, just substring them :)

Comment: can you give some more information about `Industry Number`? Is is always one letter followed by 6 digits?

Comment: use  Regex.Replace("J0123", "([A-z]*)", "");

Answer (score 4):

i assume PersonalNumber is a `Int` and IndustryNumber is has type `String`

```
bool Result = int.Parse(string.Concat(PersonalNumber.Skip(1))) == IndustryNumber;
```

Comment: `int.Parse` could be vulnerable for *integer overflow* if numbers are *long enough*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yes only for numbers below `2147483648` and this solution also doesn't work for negative personal numbers :)

Comment: Negative numbers are exotic ones :) but as for *long numbers* they are more common than we used to think.
Often numbers encode some data, e.g. `12345200009` can mean "factory #12 working place #345 hired *09 2000*"

Answer (score 2):

For the *updated* question (i.e. industry number starts with arbitrary letter followed by a number padded by zeros) it could be

```
// Remove 1st letter, than remove zeros
String number = IndustryNumber.Substring(1).TrimStart('0');

if (number.Equals(personalNumber)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RegEx:

```
var numb = int.Parse(RegEx.Match(industryNumber, @"\d+^").Value);
//Then compare the two ints
```

Comment: `int.Parse` could be vulnerable for *integer overflow* if numbers are *long enough*

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for given code below

```
  string a = "str123";
    string b = string.Empty;
    int val;

    for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
            b += a[i];
    }

    if (b.Length>0)
        val = int.Parse(b);
```

then call getInt(mystring)==int

by Dominik answer

```
    Regex.Replace("J0123", "([A-z]*)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Regex to remove the first part of the Industry number:

```
Regex.Replace("J0123", "J0*", "");
```

results in "123"

**UPDATE**, to account for all letters use this regex:

```
Regex.Replace("J0123", "[A-Z]0*", "");
```

Comment: The question has been *updated*, it seems that you have to change `J` in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use substring() on the Industry Number and Convert after:
I assume you use an array of string with 2 dimensions. string[,] myarray.

```
for (int i = 0; i<myarray.GetLengh(0);i++)
{
    //get personnal number as integer, this is simple
    int personnal = Convert.ToInt32(myarray[i][0]);

    //get industry number as integer, this is the difficult part
    string strIndustry = myarray[i][1];
    strIndustry = strIndustry.SubString(0,1);//remove the first char
    int industry = Convert.ToInt32(strindustry);//I assume that you only have numbers after the letter if not you may need to test it with tryParse...
    //then you can now compare integers
    if(personnal==industry)
    {
        //your code to execute if true
    }
    else{//...}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have two arrays for PersonalId and IndustryID.Result is another array to which will hold the result.

```
for(int i=0; i< PersonalID.Count i++)
{
if(IndustryID[i].Contains(PersonalID[i]))
{
Result[i]=true;
}
else
Result[i]=False;
}
```